# KineticJS пересечение фигур

Tags: javascript

Как на [KineticJS](http://kineticjs.com/) ловить и обрабатывать пересечение произвольных фигур?

[FabricJS](http://fabricjs.com/) позволяет [делать это](http://fabricjs.com/intersection/) из коробки, а в [KineticJS](http://kineticjs.com/) такое есть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то есть:

[`intersects(point)`](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Shape.html#intersects)

[`getAllIntersections(pos)`](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Container.html#getAllIntersections)

[`getIntersection(pos)`](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Stage.html#getIntersection)

Но это всё только для точки. А вам нужно целые фигуры сравнивать. Боюсь, что придется вручную определять пересечения. Вот легкий пример с окружностями: http://jsfiddle.net/87GhE/2/

Но по моему либа какая-то геморная (я не смог текст прикрепить к окружности, даже соединив их в группу) и я бы отказался от неё.

Comment: Видимо придется... Спасибо за помощь.